# How to decrease the Auto increment _id in android SQLite?

Tags: android, database, sqlite

In Android, I created an SQLite database containing one table, which in turn has an auto-increment ID column.

Suppose I have 4 records. When I delete all of them, the next inserted record has the ID of a 5th one (`4`), but I need to insert this record starting again from the 1st position, i.e. `0`.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Just for reference, what would be your reason for doing that?

Comment: I need to delete the data on user input and user must know record number!

Comment: yes,the user can know the user number.. just before deleting get the information of that row.. store it ,and then delete that row...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: Maybe I should make it clear that just inserting the rows with the correct id instead of manipulating the sequence number ***definitely*** is a better idea than the below method. If there's no row with id=3 in the table, you can just insert with a fixed value in the id even in an AUTOINCREMENT table.

---

That said, if you're ***really sure***, you can set the auto increment value to any value using;

```
UPDATE sqlite_sequence set seq=<next sequence no -1> where name=<table name>;
```

That is, if you want AUTOINCREMENT on the next insert on table 'TableA' to generate 5, you do;

```
UPDATE sqlite_sequence set seq=4 where name='TableA';
```

Note that resetting `seq` behaves a bit different from what you may expect, it just means that the lowest id generated will be the greater of `seq + 1` and the `max id still in the table + 1`.

That is, if you delete all values >=5, you can reset the sequence value to 4 and have 5 generated as the next sequence number, *but if you still have the id 10 in the table, the next number generated will be 11 instead*.

Maybe I should point out the fact that I cannot find this exact behavior documented anywhere, so I'd not rely on the behavior for every future version of sqlite. It works now, it may not tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
delete from your_table;    
delete from sqlite_sequence where name='your_table';
```

SQLite keeps track of the largest ROWID that a table has ever held using the special SQLITE_SEQUENCE table. The SQLITE_SEQUENCE table is created and initialized automatically whenever a normal table that contains an AUTOINCREMENT column is created. The content of the SQLITE_SEQUENCE table can be modified using ordinary UPDATE, INSERT, and DELETE statements. But making modifications to this table will likely perturb the AUTOINCREMENT key generation algorithm. Make sure you know what you are doing before you undertake such changes.

Answer (score 1):

reset value of Auto increment in you table before inserting 5th record:

SQL command :

```
ALTER TABLE [tablename] AUTO_INCREMENT=[final value]
```

Comment: I think that command is MySQL only, the question is about SQLite.